# php sqlsrv extension not loading

Tags: php, windows-10, odbc, sqlsrv

I am running php 7.3 on my local machine running windows 10 and it works perfectly with the sqlsrv extension and ODBC Driver 17. I am trying to update php to 7.4 but php will not load the extension. Anyone know why it is not loading?

Error I get:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   'php_sqlsrv_74_nts_x64' (tried: C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\PHP\v7.4\ext\php_sqlsrv_74_nts_x64 (The specified module could
>   not be found.), C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\PHP\v7.4\ext\php_php_sqlsrv_74_nts_x64.dll (The specified module
>   could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0

Comment: Where is the extension folder (what is the value for `extension_dir` key from `<?php phpinfo();?>` script execution)? Probably you need to change the extension folder in the `php.ini` configuration or set two paralel PHP installations on this PC.

Comment: extension_dir = "C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v7.4\ext\" .  The extensions dir is in the same directory as the ini file.

Comment: Also, `php_php_sqlsrv_74_nts_x64.dll` is 64-bit version of the extension, while `C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\..` is probably 32-bit installation.

Comment: I j8st checked  Settings and confirmed that it IS 64 bit.  I wanted you to be right! Any other ideas?

Comment: PHP version, PHP Driver for SQL Server vesrion, ODBC Driver version must be all 64-bit (or 32-bit). If I remember correctly, you also need Microsoft Visula C++ redistributable.

Comment: yes I have all of those things.  This is an upgrade so I have previous, working versions of php with the extension already installed

Comment: `PHP Driver for SQL` means the dll extension file, yes? `php_php_sqlsrv_74_nts_x64.dll` is not real.  That file is called `php_sqlsrv_74_nts_x64.dll`, `php_php_sqlsrv_74_nts_x64.dll` is not written anywhere except the error.  I know this is not an easy question, I wish it was.  The error is an error because it is unable to load a file that does not exist and the ini file does not say to load it either.

Comment: Yes, @Ben, `PHP Driver for SQL` is the correct `php_sqlsrv_*.dll` file.

Comment: oh yes I have that, I know that dll file is correct because it is the same one that I have installed and is used by my `PHP 7.3` installation but `73` is `74` instead.  Yes I have ODBC Driver 10, 13 and 17 installed,, so what else is there?

Comment: @Zhorov any other ideas?  This IS a weird issue.

Comment: Try with tread safe versions - `php_sqlsrv_74_ts_x64.dll`, or just for test, use 32-bit version.

Comment: @Zhorov I tried each one, ;extension=php_sqlsrv_74_nts_x64, extension=php_sqlsrv_74_ts_x64, extension=php_sqlsrv_74_nts_x86 extension=php_sqlsrv_74_ts_x86 but none of them were able to be loaded.  PHP cannot load the extension.. I have the ODBC driver, the extension, a clean version of PHP, IIS is working, are there any other variables?

Comment: Same problem here. Ever find a solution? Did all the same things you did. Got the correct ODBC drivers, C++ Runtime, etc... PHP 7.3.x runs fine. 7.4.x - no dice.

Answer (score 3):

Found a solution... You need to add the file extension to the extension= in the php.ini file.

[image: php.ini config]

So php.ini should look like this:

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_74_nts_x64.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_74_nts_x64.dll
```

Comment: This has not been necessary before. In fact, it's not necessary for any of the other extensions that come bundled with PHP either.

Answer (score 1):

You can write the complete filename in php.ini like that:

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_74_nts_x64.dll
```

But because this is supported only for legacy reasons I would recommed the format extension=<ext> without 'php_' and '.dll'. In your case:

```
extension=pdo_sqlsrv_74_nts_x64
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked! no clue why but did!